# C# mvc html.beginform send form to gmail account

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, gmail

Im making a homepage in which i want to have a form that ppl can fill in and then when clicking submit have it sent to a gmail account. I more or less want it to show up as an email without them having to fill in their own email address. I was thinking it would work out fine just sending it from the same email that is receiving it.

Problem is that it wont really get trough.

The procedure is fine since i can see all the information i fill in correctly but it wont send the mail.

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult InvitationResponseForm()
        {            
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult InvitationResponseForm(InvitationResponse model)
        {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage response = new MailMessage();
                response.From = new MailAddress("sixtofjun@gmail.com");
                response.To.Add("sixtofjun@gmail.com");
                response.Subject = model.Name + " " + model.Surname;
                string Special = model.SpecialConditions;
                string PlusOne = model.PlusOneComment;
                bool OneOrTwo = model.PlusOne;
                response.Body = model.Name + " " + model.Surname + " " + OneOrTwo + "<br><br>" + Special + "<br>" + PlusOne;
                response.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
                NetworkCredential basicAuthInfo = new NetworkCredential("sixtofjun@gmail.com", "My password");              
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = basicAuthInfo;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                return View("InvitationResponseForm", model);
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                return View();
            }

        }
```

And some of the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlusOneComment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PlusOneComment)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlusOneComment)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpecialConditions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpecialConditions)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpecialConditions)
        </div>
    </div>       

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing this for my pending wedding so really would like some help with it!
Feel free to ask for more info!

Tried alot now but still nothing successful. Can it have something to do with my ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gmail smtp port is wrong. You use "smtp.EnableSsl = true;" but still use the 465 port. I use this code and it is sending emails:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
    EnableSsl = true
};
client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
```

Comment: Ah ok. 1 step closer i guess. Altough it is still not working. When i try to send it now i get stuck at: smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated 5.5.1 ... Altough i use the right account information and it seems like all of what i am printing in is correct. I do not recieve any emails of wrongful attemtps or anything. Just that error message.

Comment: can you copy the exact error that you have. Also try to make another test email and send it from one email to another. The problem could be from that attempt. First fix your smtp connection then play with the emails.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code.                                                   Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Comment: I get it in visual studio at                                                              client.Send("from-mail", "to-mail", "test", "testbody"); Also tried a different mails. Did get one warning on my gmail account so i guess ill have to check for something there to.

Comment: try to create new gmail account for emails and just test the smtp settings with the example i gave you. If its working then use it with your code from above and see what is breaking the smtp client.

Comment: Thanks alot. This solved it. The issue i had when it still failed was because I did set the "allow less secure apps" on the wrong email address. Had multiple accounts open so.

Comment: Good that you've solved it. I didn't knew this causes this kind of problem. I would know for the future too :]